# Someone who often frowns out of anger/inmost unpleasant feelings

Tags: word-request

What do you call a person who often frowns and looks upset or angry?

The only word I found is **"Sulky"** which when I google it, strikes me as it is a sort of childish term or something!

The other idiom is found I've come accross  on this forum is **"hatched-faced"**, which based on definitions is more about facial dimentions; so not at all what I'm looking for.

I was wondering if you could help me with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the word you want is **surly**.

> irritably sullen and churlish in mood or manner [Merriam-Webster Dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/surly)

Surly implies irritation/annoyance/frustration in addition to just frowning.

Comment: Thank you @CrescentSickle; could you please let me know what's wrong with my own suggestions and what is your offer's advangate against mine?

Comment: @A-friend **Sulky** is often associated with sadness, depression, guilt, shame, etc. There isn't an aspect of anger or frustration associated with it. As for the other one, I think you mean **hatchet-faced**, but that's basically never used. In fact, the last time I ever heard it was almost a decade ago in a book where a character was named Hatchet Face. As you stated, the term refers more to facial dimensions than expressing certain emotions.